# Is there a way to create a status list in a template different than Business Intelligence?

Tags: list, business-intelligence

Can I have a status list without having to create a business intelligence center site?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can!
Simply go to the Site or Page where you'd like to have the Status List. 
Then Edit Page/Site -> Insert _> Web Part -> Business Data -> Status List
once prompted, choose the status list from the browse icon.
Enjoy